# How to generate only Component-preload.js with UI5 Tooling

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

Using Gulp/Grunt it's possible to generate a `Component-preload.js` only.
Now, I want to achieve the same result with UI5 Tooling.

To do so, I'm using the following `npm script`:

```js
ui5 build --config ./devops/ui5.yaml --exclude-task=* --include-task=generateComponentPreload
```

Unfortunately, such command generates not only a `Component-preload.js`, but a lot of other files. Is there any way to generate a `Component-preload.js` only?